# Reformatting numbers such as data0000172 to 172 in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings. Each string has the form of `data0*(\d*)` if we use a regular expression form.
The following is an example the strings:

```
data000000, data000003, data0172, data2312, data008212312
```

I would like to take only the meaningful number portion. All numbers are integers. For example, in the above case, I would like to get another list containing:

```
0, 3, 172, 2312, 8212312
```

What would be the best way in the above case?

The following is the solution that I thought:

```
import re

string_list = ["data0000172", ..... ]
number_list = []
for string in string_list:
   match = re.search("data0*(\d+)", string)
   if match:
      number_list.append(match.group(1))
   else:
      raise Exception("Wrong format.")
```

However, the above might be inefficient. Could you suggest a better way for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are *sure* that the strings start with "data", you can just slice the string and convert to integer. Leading zeroes aren't an issue there. Building an integer from a zero-padded digit strings works.

```
lst = ["data000000", "data000003", "data0172", "data2312", "data008212312"]

result = [int(x[4:]) for x in lst]
```

result:

```
[0, 3, 172, 2312, 8212312]
```

or good old replace just in case the prefix can be omitted (but it will be slightly slower):

```
result = [int(x.replace("data","")) for x in lst]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

st = 'data0000172'

a = float(re.search('data(\d+)',st).group(1))
print(a)
```

Output:

```
172.0
```

This extract the numbers i.e useful part.Apply this to your list.

Comment: Why not use int()?

Comment: you can use it. That's not a problem.Based on our need.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where the strings are might not be of the form `data<num>` and you want the solution to still be valid or if some of the entries are broken for some reason, you can do the following:

```
import re

ll = ['data000000', 'data000003', 'data0172', 'data2312', 'data008212312']
ss = ''.join(ll)
res = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\d+', ss)]
print(res)
```

The `re.findall` is applied to the entire list of strings but due to the fact it returns a list of tuples you will get the desired result.

Output:

```
[0, 3, 172, 2312, 8212312]
```

**Note**: applying the `re.findall` to the list without the join will raise an error.